# Display Percentage on HTML Tag by fetching percentage data from Doughnut Chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, plugins, chart.js

**I am new in JavaScript and I really want to know that how can we display data in form of percentage by fetching percentage data through doughnut chart using JS**

```
<div class="block-text">
             <div class="flex-chart"> <div class="box-file"></div><p class="spacing">abc</p>
             <p id = "count">20%</p></div>

             <div class="flex-chart"> <div class="box-url"></div><p class="spacing">xyz</p> 
             <p>30%</p>

         </div>
         </div>
```

**Here is the Doughnut Chart JS code:**

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4"></script>
<!--  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.7.0"></script>  -->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.0.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>

<script>
// setup 
const data = {
  //labels: ['xyz', 'abc'],
  datasets: [{
   // label: 'Weekly Sales',
    data: [12, 20],     
    backgroundColor: [
      'rgb(254, 214, 10)',
      'rgb(255, 90, 48)'

      
    ],
    borderColor: [
      "#ffffff",         
    ],
    borderWidth: 1
  }]
};

// config 
const config = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data,
 options: {
 plugins: {
  datalabels: {

    formatter: (value, ctx) => {

      let datasets = ctx.chart.data.datasets;

      if (datasets.indexOf(ctx.dataset) === datasets.length - 1) {
       var sum = datasets[0].data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
       var percentage = Math.round((value / sum) * 100) + '%';
      return percentage;
    
     } else {
       return percentage;
    
     }
   },
   color: '#fff',
 }
}        
}
}


// render init block
const myChart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('chart'),
  config
);
```

Now I want to display Percentage to get it from doughnut chart percentage variable and post it on 'abc' tag
    
       abc
                 20%

**I want percentage data in replace of 20% because 20% is static at this time**

Answer (score 0):

Check this code may be it will help you.

```
 var data = [{
   data: [50, 55, 60, 33],
   labels: ["India", "China", "US", "Canada"],
   backgroundColor: [
     "#4b77a9",
     "#5f255f",
     "#d21243",
     "#B27200"
   ],
   borderColor: "#fff"
 }];

 var options = {
   tooltips: {
     enabled: false
   },
   plugins: {
     datalabels: {
       formatter: (value, ctx) => {

         let datasets = ctx.chart.data.datasets;

         if (datasets.indexOf(ctx.dataset) === datasets.length - 1) {
           let sum = datasets[0].data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
           let percentage = Math.round((value / sum) * 100) + '%';
           return percentage;
         } else {
           return percentage;
         }
       },
       color: '#fff',
     }
   }
 };


 var ctx = document.getElementById("pie-chart").getContext('2d');
 var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'pie',
   data: {
     datasets: data
   },
   options: options
 });
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Wsmemon/w91ut860/)

Comment: sir, I think u didn't follow my question, I just want to display percentage in replace of 20% dynamically

Comment: @AhsanYazdani so you want fetch data from donut chart right?

Comment: @AhsanYazdani check this: https://jsfiddle.net/Wsmemon/w91ut860/

Comment: Yes sir, I want to fetch data from doughnut chart and want to display it in Html Heading Tag.

Comment: Ws Memon sir, I have copied your code and paste it as it is, but it doesn't work for me. It is giving an error

Comment: Sir, thank you so much for your help. It helps me alot but need to add jquery path, and it works for me. Thank you once again

Comment: Sir, just one thing required now, that is, I want to display data, when mouse cursor goes over the doughnut chart not percentage data

Comment: @AhsanYazdani check this example which will helps you alot: https://jsfiddle.net/Wsmemon/gfyhkd98/

Comment: Sir, with your previous work, I want to upgrade the work and show the data when cursor goes on Doughnut Chart, and I don't want to show percentage on Chart. https://jsfiddle.net/Wsmemon/w91ut860/ please work on this example of yours not a new one. Thank you for your support

Comment: We are very close need some more help. Please help to solve this small task

Comment: @AhsanYazdani Please check this: https://jsfiddle.net/Wsmemon/w91ut860/

Comment: please have a look on this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73134509/i-want-to-display-data-instead-of-percentages-when-cursor-hovers-over-doughnut-c